# Pre-launch TLEs for NASA launches

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight, two-line-elements, cst-100, dragon-v2

I was curious if the United States is on the verge of launching maned flights to the ISS, will anyone release Pre-Launch TLE data like was done back when the shuttle was flying.

Comment: Cool question! I've just asked [Who released pre-launch TLE data for the Space Shuttle?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34568/12102)

Comment: I've added "for NASA launches" to your title, because of "...the United States is on the verge of launching..." and I don't think you are asking about the dozens of launches by commercial companies happening regularly.