How can I find the satellite I frequently saw 20 years ago?
During my childhood, I frequently observed a satellite passing overhead, and now, 20 years later, I’m hoping to find out which satellite it was. It may no longer exist today, so historical data might be needed to identify it.
I was located in the Northern Hemisphere at latitude 37° 3' 20" N and longitude 118° 30' 40" E. Around September of 2004, I saw this satellite moving west to east horizontally across the sky at an angle of approximately 40 to 50 degrees above the northern horizon, roughly at the same height as Polaris (the North Star). The time of sighting was around 20:00(GMT+8)(I initially recalled it as 21:00, but this was incorrect), and I saw it multiple times over the course of several nights. At that time, light pollution was not severe, so the satellite appeared very obvious.
Could anyone help me calculate and identify which satellite I might have been seeing back then?

ADDITION:  When I saw this satellite back then, it was moving very fast. Looking back, it took only about a dozen seconds or so to sweep through approximately 90 degrees of the field of view in the night sky.

There could be several satellites in a near-polar sun-synchronous orbit high enough to be in sunlight at 9 pm local time in September. For a few hours after sunset there's a window where some low Earth orbits are still sunlit - so there's a good chance that it wasn't necessarily the same satellite each time, but there's also a good chance it was. I'm sure this will get one or two interesting answers.

back of the envelope math -- sunset at that time is ~6 pm local. For the satellite to be in sunlight 3 hours later, the earth will have rotated 45 degrees. Threw this into a quick cad mockup and came up with a minimum altitude of 540 km for the vehicle to be in sunlight at least until a line going straight north and south

@uhoh ... the satellite is described as travelling east-west, so it was unlikely in a polar orbit. If it was the  same altitude as Polaris (37* at that latitude) its ground track would have  been about 660km north of the observer (assuming 500km high orbit).

@Woody "I was located in the Northern Hemisphere at latitude 37°" + "at approximately a 40-degree angle above the northern horizon" suggests a polar orbit, no? Or does it suggest an impossible orbit? I think this question needs to be answered with math, not prose.

@uhoh....  If it were a polar orbit, the path would have been north/south, not west/east, regardless of the observer's latitude. And the object's altitude above the northern horizon would have been constantly changing, not a constant 40*. I think this question needs graphics, not math. I'll attend to it in a few days.

@Woody only if you found yourself in the plane of the orbit. We need math, not prose.

@uhoh oh, I initially recalled it as 21:00, but this was incorrect and it should be 20:00. This may make you confused, sorry for that.

My first guess is that it was ISS. It often makes repeated passes over a series of five or so nights. While not nearly complete in 2004, the ISS was quite large then and easily visible to the eye after sunset or before sunrise. One vehicle that can very much be ruled out is the Space Shuttle as there were no Shuttle flights in 2004 due to the January 2003 Columbia disaster. Sun synchronous satellites can also be ruled out as they would be observed going south to north or north to south at 37° latitude rather than west to east.

My second guess was that this was an airplane rather than a satellite. The recent edit suggests that this might well be the case.

As David Hammen commented, there is a chance this was the ISS.
I got an ISS TLE from Celestrak historical data for September 2004. The TLE I used is:
ISS (ZARYA) 
1 25544U 98067A   04258.02335733  .00014792  00000-0  12700-3 0  6820
2 25544  51.6340 232.2981 0005303 144.3880 334.5833 15.69613106332271

Using the ancient DOS program STSPLUS, I set the simulated time to GMT 15 September.
There was an ISS pass over the given location on that day, and it was night there.

This program does not do anything about lighting visibility as far as I know. Just shows you where the satellite is (was).
This is all considerably out of my wheelhouse, so if I made some elementary mistake, please point it out.

+1 for mentioning Dave Ransom's STSPLUS

@StevePemberton https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34573/6944

"DOS"? citation needed (humor)

This analysis is very interesting, but the ISS might not be fast enough to pass through my field of view in less than half a minute. . I have added another piece of information.

@haolee all LEO satellites move about the same speed due to orbital mechanics.  (The orbital period of a circular orbit depends only on its altitude).

@OrganicMarble ... I don't think ISS is a candidate. See edited answer below

@Woody The observer was in China. GMT +8. Better re-redit.

@OrganicMarble ... yikes! You're right! I got my E and W longitude mixed up. The geometric argument still applies for orbital inclination. Please be patient while I re-do the graphics.

Here is a comment which doesn't provide an answer but does rule out the ISS as a candidate since it puts a limit on the maximum orbital inclination of the object.

“I frequently observed”…

This limits the object to low Earth orbit (LEO) objects. These typically orbit at an altitude of 500km (ISS is about 420km). Objects in mid Earth orbit (MEO, like GPS satellites) orbit at about 12,000km). And high Earth orbit (GEO, like communication satellites) are at 36,000km. MEO and GEO objects are not visible to the unaided eye.

“a satellite passing overhead”  …

over half of orbiting objects visible with the unaided eye (commonly called “satellites”) are actually space junk. For instance, every orbital launch places an upper stage in orbit, which is usually at least as visible as its payload.

… “west to east…

Virtually all mid-inclination LEO are west to east since launches are usually in the direction of the Earth’s rotation.
It is difficult for a ground observer to accurately estimate the direction of an overhead trajectory. If we grant you the ability to estimate trajectory to within +/- 10*, this limits the possible ground tracks.


“latitude 37° 3' 20" N .”

Your observing latitude puts a limit on the orbital inclination. You would not observe an orbit whose inclination is greater than 5 degrees above or below your latitude since, at 500km altitude, it would be below your horizon


“above the northern horizon roughly at the same height as Polaris”

This narrows the ground track location further. If we assume the object’s orbital altitude is 500km, and the observed altitude above the northern horizon is 40*, the ground track is 500/tan40 or 420 km (3.8 degrees of latitude) north of the observer, or 40.9*
If the ground track’s compass direction is between 80* and 100* (as we have assumed), this gives a maximum plausible orbital inclination of 42*.
This effectively rules out the ISS as the observed object since, due to its orbital inclination of 51.6*,  it passes over China a SW-NE (or NW-SE) direction:

https://spacemath.gsfc.nasa.gov/earth/10Page111.pdf

and longitude 118° 30' 40" E

Longitude is not useful information unless the object is geosynchronous or sun synchronous. The object is not a geosynchronous object since it is visible from the ground, and not sun synchronous because it is travelling west to east rather than north/south. Objects in mid-inclination LEO have no synchronization with the Earth below.

Around September of 2004 … around 20:00

Unfortunately, this is not helpful for the same reason longitude is not helpful. LEOs are less than two hours, so any given satellite orbits several times each evening, but the object tracks over different ground each time. All LEO objects are most visible after dusk and before dawn since they are illuminated by the sun. Once they pass into the Earth’s umbra, they are not visible.
Conclusions that can be drawn from the presented information:
The object sighted was in a LEO with a minimum inclination of 41* and a likely maximum inclination of 42*. These conclusions are heavily dependent on the veracity if the estimated direction of travel.
Just for fun, I include a view of the great circle route between the observer and Baikonur Cosmodrome (at latitude 46*N). The ISS orbital inclination is slightly steeper than the red line.


Well, there are fewer satellites than seagulls...

Inclination is the wrong way to frame this.  Low inclination satellites are almost always geosynchronous, because a low altitude satellite with low inclination can't see nearly as much of the planet as a low altitude satellite with a high inclination.  Many important low altitude satellites use sun-synchronous orbits, which are all a few degrees retrograde of polar.  Both of these orbit types are chosen specifically because they do correlate with the rotation of the Earth below.  I think you mean to be talking about low altitude satellites instead.

Also "There are no visible satellites at midnight because they would be in the Earth's shadow" is definitely not true. I'm up at about 40° North, and in the high summer, there can be several visible ISS passes from the night into the morning from my location, including ones near midnight.  Here's one from 50° N, 83° W on July 10, 2024

This is a long comment, not an answer.

@RyanC ... geosynchonous satellites are not visible to naked-eye observers. Sun synchronized satellites travel north-south, not west-east. The OP is describing a LEO satellite which is not in a polar orbit. Perhaps it would be clearer if I had said "low oblique inclination" rather than "low inclination"

@notovny ...  satellites are visible later into the night during the summer because higher latitude observers are closer to the edge of the umbra. However, the OP specified the month of observation as September. Around the equinox, there would be no LEO satellites visible at midnight at 37*

@RyanC Low altitude at low inclination is good if you're trying to minimize radiation (protons and electrons).
